# struggling with partial arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string, loops

Here's the question:

Write a function called `deleteRepeats()` that has a partially filled array of characters as a formal parameter and that deletes all repeated letters from the array. Since a partially filled array requires two arguments, the function will actually have two formal parameters: an array parameter and a formal parameter of type `int` that gives the number of array positions used. When a letter is deleted, the remaining letters are moved forward to fill in the gap. This will create empty positions at the end of the array so that less of the array is used. Since the formal parameter is a partially filled array, a second formal parameter of type int will tell how many array positions are filled. This second formal parameter will be a call-by-reference parameter and will be changed to show how much of the array is used after the repeated letters are deleted. For example, consider the following code:

```
char a[10]; a[0] = 'a'; a[1] = 'b'; a[2] = 'a'; a[3] = 'c'; int size = 4;
deleteRepeats(a, size);
```

After this code is executed, the value of a[0] is 'a', the value of a[1] is 'b', the value of a[2] is 'c', and the value of size is 3. (The value of a[3] is no longer of any concern, since the partially filled array no longer uses this indexed variable.) You may assume that the partially filled array contains only lowercase letters. Embed your function in a suitable test program.

Here's what I've got so far. I just tried to work on the `deleteRepeats()` function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int max_letters = 4;

void deleteRepeats(char letters[], int size, int& numberOfLetters);

int main()
{
    char string_of_letters[max_letters] = {'a','b','a','c'};
    int letter_count = 4;



    deleteRepeats(string_of_letters, max_letters, letter_count);

    for (int i=0; i<letter_count; i++)
    {
        cout<<string_of_letters[i];
    }

    return 0;
}

void deleteRepeats(char letters[], int size, int& numberOfLetters)
{
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfLetters; i++)
    {
        if (letters[i] == letters[i+1])
        {
            for (int i=0; i<numberOfLetters; i++)
            {
                letters[i+1] = letters[i+2];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So I'm just trying to get the function to delete the repeat letters set up correctly. And my approach here doesn't seem to work. How can I fix this?

Comment: This question seems to boil down to "my code doesn't seem to work". Can you clarify the _specific_ problem?

Comment: Can you tell me whats wrong with my function deleteRepeats? All I'm trying to do is delete the number of repeated letters in the array. According to what I know, the function I wrote should be able to do that but its not doing that. Where have I gone wrong? Is that specific enough?

Comment: Besides the UB that is pointed out in the answer you are only deleting repeated letters if they are next to each other. Perhaps you should keep a list of the letters already seen and delete the current if it is in the seen list.

Comment: so i should put another for loop within to check if one letter matches more than the one next to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only checking two consecutive neighbors with `letters[i] == letters[i+1]`. Clearly, the question wants you to remove all subsequent occurrences, so that `abac` becomes `abc`. Change your algorithm to something like this:

```
void deleteRepeats(char letters[], int size, int& numberOfLetters)
{
    int k = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; ++i)
    {
        bool found = false;

        for(int j = 0; j < k; ++j)
            if(letters[i] == letters[j])
                found = true;

        if(!found)
            letters[k++] = letters[i];
    }

    numterOfLetters = k;
}
```

You might also consider starting to get familiar with STL.

Comment: Wow your code works perfectly. But I'm having trouble understanding what's really going on inside the outer for loop(I'm very new to programming). Can you possibly break down and explain to me what is going on in an iteration of the loop? One thing that confuses me is when k is initialized to 0, how could the inner for loop run, since j<k is not true for  both j and k=0?Thanks

Comment: ***how could the inner for loop run, since j<k is not true for both j and k=0?*** In that case it does not have to run since you are looking at the first letter (which there are no duplicates to that point by definition).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, when the outer for loop starts, the following chain of events occur: i is initialized to 0, i<numberOfLetters is true, i is incremented by 1, bool variable found is initialized to false, then j is initialized to 0, j<k is false so the for loop is skipped, the if statements evaluates to true so letters[0], the first character in the array gets assigned to letters[1], the 2nd place in array, then whole for loop repeats. Is this how it goes? If so, the inner for loop will never run since j<k is always false. So this really confuses me.

Comment: ***i is incremented by 1*** The increment happens after the loop body executes 1 time.

Comment: ***if statements evaluates to true so letters[0], the first character in the array gets assigned to letters[1]*** letters[0] gets assigned to letters[0] (i == 0 on the first iteration).

Comment: I suggest you single step through your debugger looking at the flow of control and the variable values at each step.

Comment: @Silvio Dante The inner `for` loop and `found` variable emulate an `std::find` algorithm (the loop *will* run n times where n is a number of unique characters that have been found), variable `k` represents the index to which the next character will be "moved", it also means the number of unique letters.

Comment: I actually wrote down by on paper each iteration beginning with zero and now I see why the function works. But I have to say I still find it pretty hard to wrap my head around. I've never encountered such a combination of loops that seems so complex. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Silvio Dante I'd not write it like this in practice, it's just loops and indexes to fit basic C++ knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, in your `deleteRepeats()` code, by using indexes like `letters[i+1]`, `letters[i+2]`, you're going out of bounds. This in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to correct the logic to

1. Limit the index to valid value.
2. Find *all* the occurrences of repeated entries. not just the adjacent ones.

Comment: but how can i do that while still covering all the letters in the array?

Comment: @SilvioDante use two different variables to maintain the index, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

1. string_of_letters should be list or vector (list is better becouse vector relocate all the elements after the segment erased to their new position).
2. You wrote "deletes all repeated letters from the array", but in your's actuall implementation you only check whether adjacent characters in array are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You code will only work for arrays that have the duplicate letters directly next to each other, but your example array has a 'b' between the two 'a's.

You could fix it by using a hash map to store letters encountered as a key then delete any character from the array that is already present in the hash map.